# Very slow simple sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have 5 tables in InnodDB, and they have in sum ~ 40million records

I want create simple filter for search contact_id with all tables.

To do this, I create the following query:

```
SELECT c.id FROM contacts AS c 
JOIN bonus_cards AS B USING(client_id) 
JOIN orders AS o USING(card_number) 
JOIN order_items AS oi USING (order_id) 
JOIN products AS p USING (product_id) WHERE p.brand_id = 125;
```

I also used a different query style:

```
SELECT c.id FROM contacts AS c 
INNER JOIN bonus_cards AS bc ON(bc.client_id=c.client_id) 
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON(bc.card_number=o.card_number) 
INNER JOIN order_items AS oi ON(o.order_id=oi.order_id) 
INNER JOIN products AS p ON(oi.product_id=p.product_id) WHERE p.brand_id = 125;
```

There is no difference in time.

The request is very long. And for a very long time it's more than 30 minutes.

I have all the necessary indices, and when I do the query query, I see that the indexes are involved.

My config my.cnf:

```
    net_read_timeout = 3600
    net_write_timeout = 3600
    wait_timeout = 120
    interactive_timeout = 120
    key_buffer_size =32M
    sort_buffer_size = 8M
    max_allowed_packet = 1M
    read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
    thread_stack = 128K
    query_cache_limit = 1M
    query_cache_size = 0
    query_cache_type = 1
    thread_cache_size = 16
    max_heap_table_size = 128M
    tmp_table_size = 128M
    innodb_open_files = 4096
    innodb_file_per_table = 1
    innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
    innodb_log_file_size = 128M
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048M
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
    #innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
    innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
    innodb_read_io_threads = 8
    innodb_write_io_threads = 8
    innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
    innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

Comment: INNER JOIN is the same as JOIN.

Comment: How many records does it return? Narrow it down maybe?

Comment: @jarlh Yes)) I know it, I wrote this so that there were no questions, I tried different ways of linking.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide Returns 0 records, because I can not wait to complete the query. Server in the down does not go away. But I waited more than 30 minutes and did not receive a response from the request.

Comment: can you show the explain? And does p.brand_id have a index?

Comment: I can understand your query almost completely, what baffles me is the `bonus_cards` table. What relation does it have with the other tables?

Comment: How big are these tables? How big are all the databases on your server?

Comment: What could help is reducing the amount of rows you search through. For instance if the product was only sold between certain dates then you can restrict the searching in the `orders` and `order_items` tables to that date range. These tables should then have dates which are indexes, of course.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yes, sure why not - [link](http://prntscr.com/iq4by0) This is a request for a production database.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware in this table the client's bonus card number is stored through which the purchase is made, and in it the client's identifier in the database is stored.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn sum = 8.2GB

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You are right, I need to have a concept of the date for the purchase period, but according to the requirements of the customer, the dates may not be.

Comment: So you have 8+GB of databases, but only 2GB of buffer pool. If you can get more memory into your buffer pool (say 12GB, to allow room for your DBs, indexes, and some working set), your whole database will run much better.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, yes your right. Do you think the problem is in the lack of RAM on the server?

Comment: No. I think your best solution will involve an index change, but that's just intuition. But I think some memory tuning will help.

Comment: It would make more sense if the `client_id` was in the `orders` table. This doesn't mean it cannot also be in the `bonus_cards`, or even that a reference to the `card_number` can be in the `orders` table, but it would cut out the `bonus_cards` tablet from between the `contacts` and `orders` tables, reducing the number of tables to join to four. All you would need then, for instance, is to test that only orders with a bonus card are used. Lots of tricks like this are possible, but you have to willing to change the database. If you're not, then only faster hardware will help.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for your comment. I know it) But) I have tests, and joins (`contacts`+`bonus_cards`+`orders`) working is well, max up time 2s. but joins(`orders`+`order_item`+`product`) so very slow.... > 7min....

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM contacts AS c JOIN 
     bonus_cards AS B USING(client_id) JOIN 
     orders AS o USING(card_number) JOIN
     order_items AS oi USING (order_id) JOIn
     products AS p USING (product_id)
WHERE p.brand_id = 125;
```

The optimal indexes are:

- `products(brand_id, product_id)`
- `order_items(product_id, order_id)`
- `orders(order_id, card_number)`
- `bonus_cards(card_number, client_id)`
- `contacts(client_id, id)`

That said, I'm surprised that you have to go through a table such as `bonus_cards` to tie an order to a contact.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but unfortunately there is no way to change this ((

Comment: And yes, these indexes are used when data is fetched.

Comment: @AlexStorm Any chance you could post your working query and companion EXPLAIN so we can see what you ended up with?  It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found bug in db structure. I'm working with a database that I was given and I did not have any changes in its integrity.

But the phrase - never believe the data, turned out to be true. The database was not the correct data types that linked the subtables.

For example:

```
contacts - client_id int 8 not null,
bonus_cards - client_id int 8 not null,
bonus_cards - card_number varchar 56 not null,
orders - card_number varchar 56 not null,
orders - order_id int 11 not null,
order_items order_id **varchar 50** not null,
order_items product_id **varchar 50** not null,
products product_id int 8 not null,
products brand_id int 8 not null,
```

I probably gave one more example, which may arise from the developers.
First of all, when debugging queries, check with the data type.

I hope I helped the community.

P.S. Speed of query execution 5s (8.2Gb database and 2gb RAM) :) easy

Comment: The lesson to learn:  Always provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` when asking about a query.  (Without it, we had no way of guessing that a datatype mismatch was the the problem.)